# can't delete folder in Docker container

Tags: docker

within a running docker container I am trying to erase a folder. However, the OS seems to find that some files are not able to delete it. During the deletion process it says something like can not find file for several files supposed to be within the folder I am trying to delete. Is there a way to repair this?

I tried:

fsck -f /MyFolder
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
fsck.ext2: Is a directory while trying to open /MyFolder

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768

OTHER error messages:

```
rm: cannot remove 'MyFolder/webpack.config.js': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'MyFolder/webpack.config.js.bck2': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'MyFolder/webpack.config.js.bck3': No such file or directory
```

I also noticed a lot of files with size 0 with the names of the files declared as 'cannot remove...'

Comment: It's a system folder? or just a folder created by you.

Comment: it is a folder I created. It might got corrupted and I don't know what to do

Comment: Can you send the error?